# When is it _not_ safe to re-run `terragrunt run-all apply`?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Terragrunt docs say, in section [Dependencies between modules](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/#dependencies-between-modules) (emphasis mine):

> If any of the modules fail to deploy, then Terragrunt will not attempt to deploy the modules that depend on them. Once you’ve fixed the error, it’s **usually** safe to re-run the run-all apply or run-all destroy command again, since it’ll be a no-op for the modules that already deployed successfully, and should only affect the ones that had an error the last time around.

So, when is it *not* "safe to re-run the `run-all apply` or `run-all destroy` command again"?

Comment: Probably an unfortunate phrasing. I can't imagine a scenario when it would not be safe to `run-all apply` unless some non-recommended practices (e.g. non-idempotent scripts) used in the module which threw the mentioned error.

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I feel at least a bit soothed now. Will keep the question opened in case others will also chime in - hoping for a Terragrunt core member. :)